# Flutter - is there a a dynamic expand and collapse function for containers?

Tags: flutter

I want to be able to dynamically add rows which will contain various widgets.  The way I'm doing it at the moment is by Creating 3 unique containers with the widgets I need and indenting them based on level, but there must be something that does this already?

I want to be able to click on the + or - button to expand or collapse the container at the bottom

The following is fully working main.dart code:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Appbar for nested'),),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: NestedStuff(),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}

class NestedStuff extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NestedStuffState createState() => _NestedStuffState();
}

class _NestedStuffState extends State<NestedStuff> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        RowWidgetOne(),
        RowWidgetTwo(),
        RowWidgetThree(),
        RowWidgetTwo(),
        RowWidgetThree(),
        RowWidgetThree(),

      ],
    );
  }
}

class RowWidgetOne extends StatelessWidget {
//   const RowWidget({
//     Key key,
//   }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25,8.0,8,25),
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget> [
            CircleAvatar(
              child: Icon(Icons.remove),
              backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
            ),
            Text('sometext'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RowWidgetTwo extends StatelessWidget {
//   const RowWidget({
//     Key key,
//   }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50,1.0,1.0,25),
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget> [
            CircleAvatar(
              child: Icon(Icons.remove),
              backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
            ),
            Text('sometext'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RowWidgetThree extends StatelessWidget {
//   const RowWidget({
//     Key key,
//   }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(75,8.0,8,25),
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.grey,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget> [
            CircleAvatar(
              child: Icon(Icons.add),
              backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
            ),
            Text('sometext'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: user a listView for that and increase the count on every click

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Visibility` widget

```
  bool _visibility = false;
  Column(
    children: [
      // first row including + and - button changing _visibility value,
      Visibility(
        visible: _visibility,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            //other children
          ],
        ),
      )
    ],
  )
```